# How exactly is this function a call-by-reference function?

Tags: php

I get this warning message:

```
PHP Notice:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/sophia/gitter/project/rational-office-2019/tmp/zog.php on line 16
```

What is in line this 'zog.php' file?

```
$the_mainrdn = &obtaino($zogcn,'mainrdn');
```

So, you would think from this warning that the **obtaino** function would have a second argument that is supposed to be called by reference - but here is the start and end of the function in question:

```
function obtaino ( $the_xcont, $the_clnom )
{
  $awesome_dom = new DOMDocument();
  $awesome_dom->loadHTML($the_xcont);
  -- <some more stuff here> --
  return $awesome_bdv;
}
```

as you can see, there is no **&** symbol before the **$the_clnom** at the opening of the function - so I do not see how this is call by reference.

So what am I missing?

Comment: you're trying to make a function call result to be by reference (`&obtaino`). That makes no sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why yes, @apokryfos - you solved the problem!!! So - why did you post that as a comment rather than as an answer?

Comment: I wasn't really sure what the problem was to be honest. Sure `&obtaino` was probably incorrect here but I'm not sure if there should be a reference somewhere else